# Managing different windows in Apple's Interface Builder

Tags: interface-builder

I'm working on Interface Builder. I don't like the fact that I have to manage multiple windows. For example if I open two xib files I can easily have six different windows scattered across my window. One problem is bringing these windows together to make a sensible arrangement. Another problem is Interface Builder doesn't remember this arrangement if I close it reopen it again. Does Interface Builder have an all-in-one view? How do you deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

Interface Builder doesn't offer much help with window management. The best way I've found to deal with it is to use Spaces and open each IB document in its own space. That at least helps to manage the clutter.

Comment: Does it really work to use Spaces? On Snow Leopard I am fighting to get exactly this idea working. It doesn't. :-( The first time IB is opened, it really uses the space I set - but the second time I open a xib, the windows scatter around in my current space - not where it should be! Bug??

Comment: Probably it's a bug. In any case, it's not good. You pretty much have to manually drag the windows where you want them each time. I close all the other windows (window, view, menu, etc.) and just leave the document window open and drag that to whichever space. After that, all IB windows associated to that document will open in the same space.

Comment: It's not a bug.  Spaces doesn't work well with programs that have sattelite windows, such as IB.  They just open in the current space.